# PYTHON: Find and Replace SUBSTR from column names - lookup from CSV

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, replace

I have 1000s of records in a csv in the following format:

mycsv:

| FIND | REPLACE |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | THOMAS |
| LMN | DICKENSON |
| DEF | PAM |
| XYZ | HARRY |

a pd.DataFrame with 1000s of rows & columns in the following format:

df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'The name is ABC': [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1],
'LMN has the Highest score': [0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1],
'Happiest is XYZ': [0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1],
'is DEF deaf?': [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0]})

| The name is ABC | LMN has the Highest score | Happiest is XYZ | is DEF deaf? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

I want the following output: (the strings that match FIND in mycsv should be replaced with the corresponding REPLACE in mycsv)

| The name is THOMAS | DICKENSON has the Highest score | Happiest is HARRY | is PAM deaf? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

Comment: `df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('ABC', 'THOMAS')` and you could run it in `for`-loop for different values in CSV file.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your csv is in the same directory as your code you can start by creating a dictionary of the find and replace values.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('lookup_file.csv')
lookup_dict = df.set_index(['FIND'])['REPLACE'].to_dict()
```

Then loop through the entries of that dictionary and use replace()

```
# create sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'The name is ABC': [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1],
                          'LMN has the Highest score': [0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1],
                          'Happiest is XYZ': [0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1],
                          'is DEF deaf?': [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0]})

# apply column name mapping
for key, value in lookup_dict.items():
    df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(key, value, regex=False)

print(df)
```